# Error de vista previa Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, diseño, descarga

Mi problema es que después de instalar y actualizar el Android Studio, me aparece un error en la pestaña de diseño que no me deja ver la apariencia de la app ni los cambios que le realizo.

**Especificaciones de PC:**

> 1. Intel i3 2328m
> 2. 4 gb Ram
> 3. Window 10 Home 64 Bits

Esos son los Errores que me muestra la pestaña de diseño

[image]

Esto me sale a la hora de tratar de descargar lo que me pide el Android Studio

[image]

Comment: ¿Has probado reiniciar Android Studio y tu pc? En la primera imagen lo que te recomiendan es reiniciar el layout, puede que sea un simple fallo temporal de Android Studio. Yo lo estoy usando mucho y más de una vez me salen errores por los que tengo que abrir y cerrar la aplicación, si el pc no es muy potente Android Studio da muchos problemas.

Comment: Si, la reinicie muchas veces, incluso lo desinstale, y tambien trata instalandolo en una pc con 8gb de ram, por si acaso era por la pc, pero me seguia saliendo el mismo error, tanto en la laptop al instalarlo de nuevo, como en la pc grande con 8gb ram, exactamente el mismo error

Comment: que version de android es ? podrias publicar tu gradle en el modulo app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer es cambiar dentro de  `/res/values/styles.xml`

esto

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

por esto

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

El problema esta en las versiones de buildTools y support library appCompat que usas

Tambien podes probar en el gradle cambiar tu appCompat por este

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

y usar el buildToolsVersion

```
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
```

Con estos cambios deberia resolver tu problema, prueba el primero y si no funciona el segundo

Comment: WOW, gracias, lo primero que me dijiste me funciono, llevaba varios días buscando y no encontraba nada, muchas gracias

Comment: un saludo anibal, de diez que te haya servido !