# Componentes bloqueados, amontonados arriba a la izquierda - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, layout, constraint-layout

Al agregar componentes al diseño, estos aparecen amontonados en un pixel en la esquina superior izquierda y no se pueden mover ni redimensionar. Ya probé varias maneras de solucionarlo que sugerian en otras publicaciones y reinstalando después de borrar la carpeta  "C:\Users....AndroidStudio3.1" pero no funcionó.
¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

En el .xml me marca que esto: **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** no está siendo utilizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el constraint layout si no creas cadenas a los elementos pasa lo que te pasa a ti, que todos se amontonan en la esquina superior izquierda, lo que tienes que hacer cada vez que creas un nuevo elemento en el layout es arrastrar los puntos que se ven en los cuatro lados del elemento, puedes arrastrarlos hacia otro elemento o hacia el borde del layout. Porque el contraint layout funciona de esa manera, por cadenas, y necesita que le indiques donde van las cadenas del elemnto.

Si Android Studio te avisa de un error relacionado con el ActionBar esta repuesta te puede servir: [Error de vista previa Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175194/error-de-vista-previa-android-studio)

Comment: Pero puedes ver los elementos en la pantalla de diseño? Prueba a crear uno desde el principio y cuando añadas un elemento indica sus cadenas, lo normal es que te funcione, si sigue fallando me lo dices.

Comment: No los puedo ver. Ya cree como cinco nuevos proyectos, reinstalé dos o tres veces el programa, cambié algunos valores en el gradle como decían en otras publicaciones, pero no hay caso. Es como si el layout estuviese bloqueado en un pixel arriba a la izquierda y me deja interactuar con los componentes que agrego, crear las cadenas y demás pero nunca llegan a ser visibles porque no salen de ese espacio.

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias!