# Problema con Textview en Android Studio y fichero Java

Tags: android-studio

Buenas recién me descargue el Android studio y tras varios problemas eligiendo el emulador (lo menciono por si tiene algo que ver) comencé a probar el Android Studio. Me han surgido dos problemas:

1. Cuando arrastro en el fichero xml un textview (o cualquier otra opción) a la pantalla que simula la de un móvil, no me aparece en dicha pantalla, sin embargo si que me aparece como que la he seleccionado abajo a la izquierda.
2. Cuando en el fichero java empiezo a programar no me detecta ningún fallo, aclarando jeje, cuando escribo cualquier tontería que no pertenezca a la sintaxis de java no me detecta que hay un error.

Muchas gracias no se si me expresé bien del todo. 
(editado)La versión de Android Studio es 3.1.3. Pongo unas fotos para aclararlo mejor:

-Pregunta 2:[Aquí se puede ver que no me reconoce que hay un error en la escritura cuando en NetBeans si que lo hace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPwh5.jpg)
Además al crear el método onCreate debería importarse una librería pero debido al fallo descrito no lo hace

-Pregunta 1:[Arrastro el text view al simulador de pantalla y no se visualiza](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSaK6.jpg)

Comment: Alfonso bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Realmente no te has explicado. No se entiende nada de lo que preguntas. Se agradece que seas más claro. Recuerda que no estamos delante de tu pantalla y debes explicarnos las cosas como si intentaras explicárselas a un párvulo. Por cierto, Android Studio no es para escribir tonterías, es para programar. El error de la pregunta 2 se resuelve entonces programando...

Comment: Como te ha dicho Cedano la explicación no es muy clara, tendrías que mejorarla para obtener una buena respuesta, pero solo por lo que he entendido tu primer error lo podrías solucionar con esta repuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175194/error-de-vista-previa-android-studio