# Ayuda con android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Lo que pasa es que se me visualiza la interfaz del celular, pero no se me visualiza lo que que se escribe, ¿Por que será?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan, posee textos (textView), pero no se visualiza lo que se escribe.

Comment: Es un error que se ha preguntado varias veces y para la mayoría de los casos ha servido [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175194/error-de-vista-previa-android-studio), espero que te sirva a ti también.

Comment: que problema tienes o te dice el textview ? podrias subir una foto ?

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema, lo que a mi me funciono fue modificar el archivo builde.gradle (Module:app) de Gradle Scripts en la parte de "dependencies" de la siguiente manera:

Originalmente esta así:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Y después de modificarlo debería quedar así:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Y los sincronizas de nuevo...
Y listo, eso debería solucionar tu problema